# necesito usar el metodo query de sequelize sobre postgres

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Buendia soy nuevo en sequelize y necesito ayuda de como usar el metodo query de sequelize, para accder a una función de una base de datos postgres, de la siguiente forma, Ej.: (select * from esquema.nombre_funcion() ),

const fn_resultados_datos_periodo = require('../models').fn_resultados_datos_periodo;
function buscar(req, res) {

```
fn_resultados_datos_periodo.query('select * from indicadores.fn_resultados_fiscalias_periodo()').then((results, metadata) => {
    results.status(200).send({ results })
});
```

}
module.exports = {
    buscar
}

estoy usando node.js, postgres, favor estimados necesito vuestra ayuda

Comment: Hola, te aconsejo leer el [tour] para entender cómo se espera que hagas una buena pregunta y por qué a menudo es necesario aportar un [mcve] o al menos algo de código donde crees que está el problema

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debes utilizar 'sequelize.query' siendo 'sequelize' el export de tu archivo de conexión a base de datos. Puedes guiarte de la documentación.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

Este es el archivo '..database/database'

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
export const sequelize = new Sequelize('pichincha1', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
host: '172.16.179.31',
dialect: 'postgres',
pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    require: 50000,
    idle: 60
},
logging: false
```

});

Aquí implementas el 'sequelize.query'

```
import { sequelize } from '../database/database'; /* aquí está la configuración de tu conexión a base de datos*/
sequelize.query('select * from indicadores.fn_resultados_fiscalias_periodo()').then((results, metadata) => {
results.status(200).send({ results })
```

});